# Posting messages to Facebook group's wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to post a message on the wall of the group, using a graph API?
If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes providing your user is a member and has allowed the publish_stream permissions for your app.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/#posts